# Accessing the original index after group-by operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

Having a DF with columns A and B, I would like to add additional column C which will include the combination of A and B values per row. I.e., if I have a DF:

```
   A B 
0  1 1
1  1 2
2  2 1
3  2 2
```

I would like to create:

```
   A B C
0  1 1 1_1
1  1 2 1_2
2  2 1 2_1
3  2 2 1_2
```

Obviously, I can go over all rows of the DF and just merge the values. Which is very SLOW for large tables. I can also use `.unique()` for columns A and B and iterate over all combinations, creating vectors `col1_un` and `col2_un` respectively, and then updating the relevant indexes in the table using something like

```
    cols_2_merge = ['A','B']
    col1_un = DF[cols_2_merge[0]].unique()
    col2_un = DF[cols_2_merge[1]].unique()
    for i in range(len(col1_un)):
        try:
            ind1 = np.where(DF[cols_2_merge[0]].str.contains(col1_un[i], na=False))[0]
        except:
            ind1 = np.where(DF[cols_2_merge[0]] == col1_un[i])[0]
        for j in range(len(col2_un)):
            try:
                ind2 = np.where(DF[cols_2_merge[1]].str.contains(col2_un[j], na=False))[0]
            except:
                ind2 = np.where(DF[cols_2_merge[1]] == col2_un[j])[0]

            new_ind = col1_un[i] + '-' + col2_un[j]
            tmp_ind = np.in1d(ind1, ind2)
            ind = ind1[tmp_ind]
            if len(ind) > 0:
                DF[new_col_name][ind] = new_ind
```

This is still SLOW. I can play with it a bit more not searching over the entire DF but reducing the field of search to indexes that weren't changed thus far. Still SLOW.

There is the option of group by that does exactly what I want, finding all unique pairs of combinations of the two columns and it's relatively fast, but I haven't figured out how to access the index of the original DF for each group.
Help please?

Comment: Does this work: `df['C'] = df['A'].astype(str) + '_' + df['B'].astype(str)`?

Comment: How does `2 2` become `1_2` ?

Comment: It was supposed to be 2_2 - type ;-(

Comment: @user3861925 Put it in an answer then

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this without using groupby, just use the fact that on strings `+` means concatenation, and that pandas does this elementwise on series:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].astype(str) + '_' + df['B'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

@joris - thank you very much. 
It did work, of course! FAST, I need to add :-)

For more complicated group-based combinations one can use

```
GB = DF[cols_2_merge].groupby(cols_2_merge)
for i in GB.groups:
    DO WHATEVER YOU WANT...
```

Thanks again!